# How to split the data into two or more csv file on the basis of csv headers(columns)

Tags: python, pandas, csv

Hey guys i have a program which reads the csv file and randomly generate data and dump it to the another csv file...now i got a csv file which have 100 columns in which 30 columns belongs to some other data but while generating at last i want to split that data into two different csv file by appending some common columns which is common for both the csv file. This is the csv sample data:

```
A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3  C1  C2  C3
1   1   1   1   2   2   2   3   3   3
1   1   1   1   2   2   2   3   3   3
1   1   1   1   2   2   2   3   3   3
```

In this A is common for both the file so output data should look like this:

```
A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3
1   1   1   1   2   2   2
1   1   1   1   2   2   2
1   1   1   1   2   2   2


A1  A2  A3  A4  C1  C2  C3
1   1   1   1   3    3   3
1   1   1   1   3    3   3
1   1   1   1   3    3   3
```

For getting one csv file with all the conditions i have written a code this is the fiddle link for it :https://pyfiddle.io/fiddle/6c547de1-eca3-4e86-bf85-bfa9eba6e653/?m=Uploaded%20file(s)

This is complicated to understand so in simple :
i'm reading a csv file:

```
df=pd.read_csv("somefile.csv")
```

doing all computation operation here and also adding three more columns that is srid ,Year, Month so Year and month at the time of data generation and srid at last...
    final_Array.append(values) # "final_Array" contains the data for all the columns. and after that i'm appending it to the dataframe.

```
data = pd.DataFrame(final_Array) to dump it to the csv file .....
```

**But i'm not getting how to split this data value into two files** this all operation is to get the all the data into single file is there any way that i can split the data which already generated before writing into the csv file ...appreciate the help thanks

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use `startswith` with ~ operator to discard the columns,

```
A_C = df1[df1.columns[~df1.columns.str.startswith('B')]]

    A1  A2  A3  A4  C1  C2  C3
0   1   1   1   1   3   3   3
1   1   1   1   1   3   3   3
2   1   1   1   1   3   3   3


A_B = df1[df1.columns[~df1.columns.str.startswith('C')]]


    A1  A2  A3  A4  B1  B2  B3
0   1   1   1   1   2   2   2
1   1   1   1   1   2   2   2
2   1   1   1   1   2   2   2
```

If you want to directly write the data frame to csv, try

```
df1[df1.columns[~df1.columns.str.startswith('C')]].to_csv('A_B.csv', index = False)
```

Comment: sorry for late response and thnx lot for the answer but i have doubt that here just for sample i have taken the columns name which is common to each other what if i have a unique columns name with atleast 50 columns so how should i select the column in that conditions?? Is this same startwith will work there or shall it works with slicing in this function please clear it...thnx

Comment: maam i tried with this way : A_C = df[df.columns[~df.columns.str.startswith(df.columns[1])]] by using the col index i can remove the particular col but "df.iloc[0:,:3]" is not working if this would working i can remove any number of col please suggest me any proper way of doing this...thnx

Comment: Column index won’t work with starts with. What are the column names?

Comment: If you want to select first three columns, df.iloc[:, :3] should work

Comment: its showing error: bad operand type for unary ~: 'Float64Index'

Comment: acutally i have more than 100 columns few of them is like that :Asset_Id', 'Asset Family', 'Asset Name', 'Location', 'Asset Component',
       'Keywords', 'Conditions', 'Parts'

Comment: this way its working (df.columns[1]) its removing one column is there any way to select multiple index at a time so i can remove others also ?

Comment: thnx for your answer but after reading through the dataframe documentation i got new function called "drop" actually i'm new to python so don't know lots of functionality never mind this drop() works :"df.drop(df.iloc[:,:4], axis=1)" now i can able to drop that column temporarily and get the different csv file with different columns ...please update in your answer if you got any new function for this operation...